# index column undefined after resampling a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I created a dataframe df5 :

```
df5 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Demonstrator/Downloads/Listeequipement.csv',delimiter=';', parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format = True)
df5['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df5['TIMESTAMP'], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
df5['date'] = df5['TIMESTAMP'].dt.date
df5['time'] = df5['TIMESTAMP'].dt.time
date_debut = pd.to_datetime('2015-08-01 23:10:00')
date_fin = pd.to_datetime('2015-10-01 00:00:00')
df5 = df5[(df5['TIMESTAMP'] >= date_debut) & (df5['TIMESTAMP'] < date_fin)]
df5.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 8645 entries, 145 to 8789
Data columns (total 9 columns):
TIMESTAMP                 8645 non-null datetime64[ns]
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1    8645 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3    8645 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5    8645 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F6    8645 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F7    8645 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F8    8645 non-null float64
date                      8645 non-null object
time                      8645 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(6), object(2)
memory usage: 675.4+ KB
```

Then, I resampled it by day like this :

```
df5 = df5.set_index('TIMESTAMP')
df5 = df5.resample('1d').mean()
df5.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 61 entries, 2015-08-01 to 2015-09-30
Freq: D
Data columns (total 6 columns):
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1    61 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3    61 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5    61 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F6    61 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F7    61 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F8    61 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(6)
memory usage: 3.3 KB
```

After, I try to assign for each timestamp a date, a time and a day of week like this :

```
df5['date'] = df5['TIMESTAMP'].dt.date
df5['time'] = df5['TIMESTAMP'].dt.time

df5['day_of_week'] = df5['date'].dt.dayofweek

days = {0:'Mon',1:'Tues',2:'Weds',3:'Thurs',4:'Fri',5:'Sat',6:'Sun'}

df5['day_of_week'] = df5['day_of_week'].apply(lambda x: days[x])
```

But As the Timestamp become an index of a dataframe when resampling,  I get a problem :

> ```
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py
> ```
>
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>          1944             try:
>       -> 1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>          1946             except KeyError:
>
> ```
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)()
>
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)()
>
> pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> ```
>
> (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)()
>
> ```
> pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> ```
>
> (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)()
>
> ```
> KeyError: 'TIMESTAMP'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-164-9887c2fb7404> in <module>()
> ----> 1 df5['date'] = df5['TIMESTAMP'].dt.date
>       2 df5['time'] = df5['TIMESTAMP'].dt.time
>       3 
>       4 df5['day_of_week'] = df5['date'].dt.dayofweek
>       5 
>
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
> ```
>
> in **getitem**(self, key)
>          1995             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
>          1996         else:
>       -> 1997             return self._getitem_column(key)
>          1998 
>          1999     def _getitem_column(self, key):
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
> ```
>
> in _getitem_column(self, key)
>          2002         # get column
>          2003         if self.columns.is_unique:
>       -> 2004             return self._get_item_cache(key)
>          2005 
>          2006         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
> ```
>
> in _get_item_cache(self, item)
>          1348         res = cache.get(item)
>          1349         if res is None:
>       -> 1350             values = self._data.get(item)
>          1351             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
>          1352             cache[item] = res
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py
> ```
>
> in get(self, item, fastpath)
>          3288 
>          3289             if not isnull(item):
>       -> 3290                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
>          3291             else:
>          3292                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py
> ```
>
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>          1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>          1946             except KeyError:
>       -> 1947                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>          1948 
>          1949         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
>
> ```
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)()
>
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)()
>
> pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> ```
>
> (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)()
>
> ```
> pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> ```
>
> (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)()
>
> ```
> KeyError: 'TIMESTAMP'
> ```

Have you an idea please to resolve this problem?  Thank you in advance

Kind regards

Comment: Once it becomes the index you need to access the index not a column: `df5['date'] = df5.index.date
df5['time'] = df5.index.time` e.t.c.

Comment: @EdChum thank you and for df5['day_of_week'] = df5['date'].dt.dayofweek  ?

Comment: When it's an index you dont need `.dt`

Comment: Ok  but when I did df5['day_of_week'] = df5['date'].dayofweek   I get this error : 'Series' object has no attribute 'dayofweek'

Comment: `df['date']` is a column (not the index) so there you need `.dt`

Comment: @PaulH thank you very much it works

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the column in the dataframe even after you assign it as the index like this:

```
df5 = df5.set_index('TIMESTAMP', drop=False)
```

Comment: when I did : "df5 = df5.set_index('TIMESTAMP')
df5 = df5.resample('1d').mean()
df5 = df5.set_index('TIMESTAMP', drop=False)"   I get an error : "
pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)()

KeyError: 'TIMESTAMP'